# Spring component annotation compile time scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, startup

My belief is that the Spring bootstraps

- ContextLoaderListener
- DispatcherServlet

due to the instruction

```
<context:component-scan base-package=" ..... " />
```

would perform component scans at app startup (or whenever instructed to) during run-time.

Is there a way to instruct the compiler (perhaps thro a maven build plugin) to perform a one time static scan of annotated spring components during build/compile time, so that the bootstrap component scan is not performed, WITHOUT abandoning the use of component annotation?

As a way to reduce startup load and latency.

Comment: That would be cool. I've not heard of such a plugin. You would have to then disable your configuration at runtime.

Comment: Firstly inversion of control frameworks add startup latency, but that's all... Unless your app takes an incredible long time to startup there is no point in wanting to do this. Secondly, we moved away from XML configuration and component scans because we found Spring Java config to be more explicit... as an added bonus startup times improved

Comment: Missing "irrelevantly vital" piece of info: I was grappling in my mind on moving an app to google-app-engine. As gae recommends that as much activities as possible be moved to compile time. But I want this to be a general question not tied to gae.

Comment: I share this concern.
Deploy time is important : may it be for the time it takes to deploy / debug / retry : Having a context.xml generated at build time would definitely improve the workflow time.

I think if would not be difficult to create a maven plugin that filter context.xml resources and expand 
<context:component-scan base-package=" ..... " /> into individual bean declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Spring 5** Has added a new feature to improve startup performance of large applications.

*it creates a list of component candidates at compilation time.*

In this mode, all modules of the application must use this mechanism as, when the ApplicationContext detects such index, it will automatically use it rather than scanning the classpath.

**To generate the index,**  we just need to add below dependency to each module

**Maven:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:5.0.3.RELEASE")
}
```

This process will generate a **META-INF/spring.components** file that is going to be included in the jar.

Reference : [1.10.9. Generating an index of candidate components](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-index)

Comment: in Gradle 4.6+ (that includes Gradle 5.x - I have verified in Gradle 5.1.1 and 5.2), the correct declaration is annotationProcessor 'org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:5.1.4.RELEASE'.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22338

Answer (score 3):

Spring 5 has added an option of [generating an index of candidate components at compile time](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-index). When the index is found, only the index is used and full classpath scan is skipped.